# Approval process fails with Invalid cross reference keu

Tags: force.com, approval-process

I am getting error while assigning the Related user field of my approval object in the approval step. If I use the same user in the step as user then works fine. Any help would be great.

System.DmlException: Process failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: [] 22:11:56.561 (561627427)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[114]|Approval.process(Approval.ProcessRequest) 22:11:56.561

I have provided all permission and everything.

thanks
Sm

Comment: screenshot would be helpful here